# mail is not sent by app-engine it stuck in Task Queue no error is generated

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-mail

I've used github project jappstart https://github.com/taylorleese/google-app-engine-jappstart
as an example but after deploying application into app-engine in prod can't make application to send authorisation emails.

As well no Unauthorised sender error is generated in app-engine logs so looks like I'm using correct sender email. I realised that in Task Queues mail queue is generated but pressing run now button is not helping :/ Any Idea ?

prod properties file

```
google.app.id= -Application Identifier-
google.app.version=1

google.jsapi.http.key=enterKey
google.jsapi.https.key=enterKey

application.secureChannel=https
application.hostname= -Application Identifier Alias-

jquery.ver=1.7.1

mail.fromAddress= -owner/admin email-
```

ActivationEmail method

```
public final void sendActivationEmail(final UserAccount user,
    final String locale)
    throws MessagingException {
    final Properties props = new Properties();
    final Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    final Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    final Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    final MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    final MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();

    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(getFromAddress()));
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
        new InternetAddress(user.getEmail()));

    message.setSubject(messageSource.getMessage("mail.subject", null,
        new Locale(locale)));

    textPart.setContent(messageSource.getMessage("mail.body.txt",
        new Object[] {getHostname(), user.getActivationKey()},
        new Locale(locale)), "text/plain");

    htmlPart.setContent(messageSource.getMessage("mail.body.html",
        new Object[] {getHostname(), user.getActivationKey()},
        new Locale(locale)), "text/html");

    multipart.addBodyPart(textPart);
    multipart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);
    message.setContent(multipart);

    Transport.send(message);
}
```